# Order of parameters in <*> and parenthesis in Scala

Tags: scala, scalaz, applicative

The `<*>` seems to be defined as a method of `M[A]`, which accepts `M[A=>B]`. That's why I need parenthesis:

```
val f: A => B => C = ...
val as: List[A] = ...
val bs: List[B] = ...
val cs: List[C] = ...
val r = cs <*> (bs <*> (as <*> List(f)))
```

On the other hand if I define `<*>` as a method of `M[A=>B]`, which accepts `M[A]`, I can write

```
val r = List(f) <*> ma <*> mb <*> mc
```

Does it make sense ?